# unexplained error on contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, remix, revert

My contract is reverting for a random reason and I cannot find out why. I have set a revert message to all my requires() but when I try to send a transaction via remix it does not work for a specific function. Other functions work but there is just this functions that randomly reverts. Can someone explain causes of reverts? I am sending the transaction through remix and other transactions work so its not an error with the contract address or ABI. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you paste the contract code?

Comment: @Safi, it is a couple hundred lines long. How can I paste it?

Comment: Paste the code of that function that you are referring.

Comment: If you are unable to paste the code then at least paste the error.
It is impossible to answer without actually reading the error.

Comment: There is no error, just "execution reverted"